# not able to find mistake in python class

Tags: python, lambda, aws-codepipeline

Below is my code. I am having an issue with this class. this is not a full code but only the class. if you check the if/else condition at last, I am calling the function " check_deployment_update_status(job_id)" which is outside of class. I am having an issue there.

My code is running fine till that line. but after that i am not getting output from that function. So, I am thinking that function is not getting called at the end. can anyone help why after if/else operation function is not getting called.

FYI-
what my code do is, this code in lambda and it's integrated in codepipeline. this function is use for deployment to Elastic beanstalk from codepipeline through lambda. I am trying to integrate continues token which can keep continue the lambda, so lambda can check the status of job it's done, running or failed. if anyone did this before with codepipeline and lambda, please leave a comment.

```
class Env():    
    def start_deployment(self,job_id,cpname):
        EB1 = cpname+"1"
        EB2 = cpname+"2"
        print EB1
        print EB2   

        if cpname.endswith("dev"):
            NewEnvName = cpname.replace('dev','qa')
        elif cpname.endswith("qa"):
            NewEnvName = cpname.replace('qa','stage')
        elif cpname.endswith("stage"):
            NewEnvName = cpname.replace('stage','prod')

        NewEB1 = NewEnvName+"1"
        NewEB2 = NewEnvName+"2"
        EnvEB1 = client.describe_environments(
                EnvironmentNames=[EB1]
                )
        print EnvEB1

        EnvEB2 = client.describe_environments(
            EnvironmentNames=[EB2])
        print EnvEB2
        if EnvEB1['Environments']:
            cnameEB1 = EnvEB1['Environments'][0].get('CNAME')
            print cnameEB1
            if '-blue' in cnameEB1:
                CheckVersion = EB2
                App_Version = client.describe_environments(EnvironmentNames=[CheckVersion])
                print App_Version
                VersionLabel = App_Version['Environments'][0]['VersionLabel']
                print VersionLabel

            elif '-green' in cnameEB1:
                CheckVersion = EB1
                App_Version = client.describe_environments(EnvironmentNames=[CheckVersion])
                print App_Version
                VersionLabel = App_Version['Environments'][0]['VersionLabel']
                print VersionLabel


        EnvEB1 = client.describe_environments(
                EnvironmentNames=[NewEB1]
                )
        print EnvEB1

        EnvEB2 = client.describe_environments(
            EnvironmentNames=[NewEB2])
        print EnvEB2

        self.Env = ""
        if EnvEB1['Environments']:
            cnameEB1 = EnvEB1['Environments'][0].get('CNAME')
            print cnameEB1
            if '-blue' in cnameEB1:
                self.Env = NewEB1
                print self.Env
                update_env = client.update_environment(
                    EnvironmentName = self.Env,
                    VersionLabel = VersionLabel)
                print update_env
                check_deployment_update_status(job_id)

            elif '-green' in cnameEB1:
                self.Env = NewEB2
                print self.Env
                update_env = client.update_environment(
                    EnvironmentName = self.Env,
                    VersionLabel = VersionLabel)
                print update_env
                check_deployment_update_status(job_id)
```

Comment: You're not printing or returning anything.  How do you know what the return value of `check_deployment_update_status` is?

Comment: Why should i need to print or return here. Because that function has all that operation. Still i need to return or print that here?

Comment: Done, Thanks for your comment. I was getting a value which i was returning on that function but that was not correct value.

Comment: you get no output from `start_deployment` because there is no return anywhere, and after your call to `check_deployment_update_status(job_id)` there is no more code to execute (and any return value that it may have is discarded) so `start_deployment` ends right there